# Custom scalar on apollo server

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Im trying to define a custom scalar on apollo server, so far here is what i've got

Custom scalar file (timestamp.js)

```
import { isRFC3339 } from 'validator';
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';

export default new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Timestamp',
  description: 'RFC3339 Timestamp format',
  serialize(value) {
    if (isRFC3339(value)) {
      return value;
    }
    throw new Error('Timestamp cannot represent an invalid RFC-3339 Timestamp string');
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    if (isRFC3339(value)) {
      return value;
    }
    throw new Error('Timestamp cannot represent an invalid RFC-3339 Timestamp string');
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (isRFC3339(ast.value)) {
      return ast.value;
    }
    throw new Error('Timestamp cannot represent an invalid RFC-3339 Timestamp string');
  }
});
```

In my schema, my schema is in several files, but I join them together before passing them to makeExecutableSchema.

```
scalar Timestamp
```

On the file that has the makeExecutableSchema that later on is exported and user in my server constructor.

```
import timeStamp from './scalars/timeStamp';
.
.
.
.
const schema = {
  typeDefs: [
    myTypeDefs
  ],
  resolvers: merge(
    resolvers,
    timeStamp
  ),
};

export default makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schema.typeDefs,
  resolvers: schema.resolvers
});
```

I dont know what im missing because i have this error when trying to run my API

```
throw new _1.SchemaError("\"" + typeName + "\" defined in resolvers, but has invalid value \"" + resolverValue + "\". A resolver's value " +
            ^

Error: "name" defined in resolvers, but has invalid value "Timestamp". A resolver's value must be of type object or function.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've checked what type of thing timeStamp when i import it and it is in fact an object and has the propert keys from the GraphQLScalarType

Comment: What is the `merge` function you're calling to create your resolvers object? Is that `lodash`?

Comment: Sorry, yes i forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building a schema using `apollo-server` (or `graphql-tools`), the `resolvers` parameter must be an object whose properties are either

- the name of an output object type in your schema
- the name of a (custom) scalar type
- the name of an enum type

In other words, the resulting object should look something like:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    // field resolvers here...
  },
  // Maybe some other object types here...
  Timestamp: timeStamp,
}
```

Note that for our custom scalars, the property name needs to match the name we've specified for the scalar. This is also the same name you include in your `typeDefs`. In this case, the property would be `Timestamp` and we would set it to the `GraphQLScalarType` we instantiated.

So, assuming your actual `resolvers` variable is correctly formatted, you need to do:

```
merge(
  resolvers,
  { Timestamp: timeStamp }
)
```

Alternatively, you can also change your timeStamp's default export...

```
export default { Timestamp: new GraphQLScalarType(...) }
```

or just forgo using `merge` altogether using spread syntax :)

```
resolvers: {
  ...resolvers,
  Timestamp: timeStamp,  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and detailed, such a small detail that had my head broken.